# Implement backspace for character set having 1 and 2 byte characters

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

character set has 1 and 2 byte characters. One byte characters have 0 as the first bit. You just
keep accumulating the characters in a buffer. Suppose at some point the user types a backspace, how
can you remove the character efficiently.

one solution that came in my mind is that there is no need to think about one byte characters (it has 0 as most significant bit) and only we need to think about 2 byte characters and how it could be differentiated from 1 byte character.I thought to include and extra bit (say 0) to 2 byte char to distinguish it but that would eat up many character representations.

suggest an idea!

Comment: This problem can be dealt with, but can I ask why you are using two different sizes of characters? There's a slew of issues that you're going to need to check for (such as buffer sizes, for example) if the size of your characters are different. IMHO you should consider just making all characters 2 bytes in order to simplify your solution.

Comment: Is this a real-life problem or just an exercise??

Comment: 1st of all this is an exercise.. making all character 2 byte could waste a lot of memory!!

Comment: @pravs - wasting memory is usually ok. Having to add tons of unnecessary checks to your program is usually not.

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it with the "Homework" tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean first bit?
In the 2-octet value `0xfade` (*`0b1111101011011110`*) is the first bit a `0` or a `1`?

Anyway, you can arrange to write the values in little-endian or big-endian format to have the "first bit" always written last. By examining only the last octet written you know whether to delete 1 or 2 octet.

Comment: 1st bit means MSB and its 1 in your example

Comment: Ok ... write the values in little-endian format. The sequence `0x42 0x43 0xfa77` would be written as `0x42 0x43 0x77 0xfa`. When you get a backspace, check the last value written (`0xfa`) and delete 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit like homework, but...

If you're accumulating them in a buffer, then a "backspace" just means move the write pointer backwards in the buffer (and possibly writing a NUL at the new write head). One very simple implementation is this:

```
On backspace:
  Move write pointer back one byte
  If MSB != 0:
    Move write pointer back one byte
  Write NUL at current position
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: This solution is flawed. Suppose the last character was two bytes, this characters second byte could begin with zero, but your algorithm would decrement the buffer only one byte.

Comment: @ricola86 I did think of that, but I wasn't sure given the problem definition. He stated unequivocally "one byte chars have 0 as MSB." To me, that implied "two byte chars never have 0 as MSB." In whatever system this is, he could enforce two byte characters always setting MSB on the second byte. Perhaps it's my assumption that was flawed, however.

Comment: @denniston.t: ricola86 said it right and real problem is when this 2 byte character has 1 as MSB

Comment: @pravs That doesn't make complete sense to me... If a 2-byte character always has 1 as MSB (assuming you meant on the second byte), then this algorithm works. Whether or not it has 1 as MSB on the first byte is irrelevant. (Terminology: in two byte char `0x0103`, "first byte" = `0x01`, "second byte" = `0x03`). Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: @pravs I'm completely confused, what exactly are the constraints?? Is the first bit of the second byte (of a two-byte character) always 1? if so the solution above works.

Comment: If I'm understanding the OP correctly, this would be a working solution if the if statement was changed to be "If ((curIndex > 0) && (MSB(byte at curIndex - 1) != 0))".

Answer (score 0):

Don't make up your own character set or encoding; use UTF-8.  Then it is easy to find the beginning of the character before the write pointer (it is the nearest octet whose two highest bits are not 0x10).  Mind, then characters can be *longer* than two octets, but that's necessary anyway; there are more than 65,792 characters.